# Figuring out best solution for a Maze solver, with animated output

Tags: c++, gif, maze, fltk

## Abstract

My ultimate goal is to use Fltk to take user inputs of pixels, display a generated maze (either my own, or fetch it from the website mentioned in the details), and then show the animated solution.

This is what i've managed so far:
https://giant.gfycat.com/VioletWelloffHatchetfish.webm

## Details

I'm in my first c++/algorithm class of a bachelors in CE.

As we've been learning about graphs, dijkstra etc. the last weeks i decided after watching Computerphile's video about Maze solving, to try to put the theory into "practice".

At first i wanted to output a maze from this site, http://hereandabove.com/maze/mazeorig.form.html, with the plotted solution. I chose that walls and paths should be 1x1 pixel, to make it easier to make into a 2D-vector, and then a graph.

This went well, and my program outputs a solved .png file, using dijkstra to find the shortest path.

I then wanted to put the entire solution in an animated gif.

This also works well. For each pixel it colors green/yellow, it passes an RGBA-vector to a gif-library, and in the end i end up with an animated step by step solution.

I also for each RGBA-vector passed to the gif-library, scale it up first, using this function:

```
//Both the buffer and resized buffer are member variables, and for each //plotted pixel in the path it updates 'buffer', and in this function makes a //larger version of it to 'resized_buffer'
// HEIGHT and WIDTH are the original size
// nHeight and nWidth are the new size.
bool Maze_IMG::resample(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    if (buffer.size() == 0) return false;
        
    resized_buffer.clear();
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nWidth * nHeight * 4; i++) resized_buffer.push_back(-1);

    double scaleWidth = (double)nWidth / (double)WIDTH;
    double scaleHeight = (double)nHeight / (double)HEIGHT;

    for (int cy = 0; cy < nHeight; cy++)
    {
        for (int cx = 0; cx < nWidth; cx++)
        {
            int pixel = (cy * (nWidth * 4)) + (cx * 4);
            int nearestMatch = (((int)(cy / scaleHeight) * (WIDTH * 4)) + ((int)(cx / scaleWidth) * 4));

            resized_buffer[pixel] = buffer[nearestMatch];
            resized_buffer[pixel + 1] = buffer[nearestMatch + 1];
            resized_buffer[pixel + 2] = buffer[nearestMatch + 2];
            resized_buffer[pixel + 3] = buffer[nearestMatch + 3];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

## Problems

The problem is that it takes a looong time to do this while scaling them up, even with "small" mazes at 50x50 pixels, when trying to scale them to say 300x300. I've spent a lot of time to make code as efficient and fast as possible, but after i added the scaling, stuff that used to take 10 minutes, now takes hours.

In fltk i use the Fl_Anim_Gif-library to display animated gifs, but it wont load the maze gifs that has been scaled up (still troubleshooting this).

## My real questions

Is it possible to improve the scaling function, so that it does not take forever? Or is this a totally wrong approach?

Is it a stupid idea to try to display it as a gif in fltk, would it be easier to just draw it directly in fltk, or should i rather try to display the images one after another i fltk?

I'm just familiarizing myself with fltk. Would it be easier now to use something like Qt instead. Would that be more beneficial in the long run as far as learning a GUI-library goes?

I'm mainly doing this for learning, and to start building some sort of portfolio for when i graduate. Is it beneficial at all to make a gui for this, or is this a waste of time?

Any thoughts or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is resized_buffer?  Is it a vector?  Have you used vector.reserve to set aside the space so it does not keep allocating?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever graphics package you use, the performance will be similar.  It depends on how you handle the internals.  For instance,

1. If you write it to a buffer and BLT it to the screen, it would be faster than writing to the screen directly.
2. If you only BLT on the paint event, it would be faster than forcing and update every time the screen data changes.
3. If you preallocate the buffers then the system does not have to keep on reallocating whenever the buffer space runs out.
4. Assuming that the space is preallocated, it can be written to without clearing first.  Every cell it going to be written to so no need to clear, allocate and and reallocate.